# HTML/CSS Dropdown menu not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

After finishing the dropdown menu on my desktop, I wanted to see how it worked on mobile. the issue is that on my ipad, the bootstrap panel I have stretches across the screen, so the dropdown get cut off by the panel. I can use a few `<br>`, but I'm sure there's another way. Can I either stop the panel from stretching, or make the dropdown menu show on top of the panel, rather than under it? On my desktop the panel is on the left side of the screen. How can I make it stay that way?

my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>| Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet"               href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.cs  s"
 integrity="sha384-    1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"     crossorigin="anonymous" />

    </head>

   <body>



    <div id="nav">
        <div id="nav_wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">H</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">A</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">C</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Tr</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Last 24 hours</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">View All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Deadliest</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="headerBreak">

        </div>

    <div class="recent">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                       <div class="headingPanel">
                         <div class="panel-heading"><center><span class="label label-danger">Recent</span></center></div>
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"><center>Most     Recent</center></h3>
                        </div>
                           </div>



                        <div class="panel-body">                  
                            <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Location</th>
                                <th>More Info</th>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>01/28/16</td>
                                <td>Missouri</td>
                                <td><a href="#">More Info</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                            <center><input type="button" value="View all" onClick="#" class="btn btn-default"></center>
                            <center><input type="button" value="Last 24 hours" onClick="#" class="btn btn-default"></center>
                            <center><input type="button" value="Last      48 hours" onClick="#" class="btn btn-default"></center> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="panelFooter">
                                <p>Last Updated: 01/28/16</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>











    </body>
</html>
```

My css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body 
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* Navigation */

#nav
{
    background-color: #222;
}

#nav_wrapper
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}


#nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#nav ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul li:hover
{
    background-color: #333;
}

#nav ul li a,visited
{
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover
{
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul ul li
{
    display: block;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
}

#nav ul ul
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
}

#nav ul ul li
{
    display: block;
}

#nav ul ul li a,visited
{
    color: #ccc;
}

#nav ul ul li a:hover
{
    color: #099;
}






/*
.headerBreak
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: -125px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #a7e0ee;
}
*/

 .recent 
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;


}

.recent input
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
}


.panel-body
{
    background-color: white;
}

.panel-heading
{
    background-color: #999;
    color: #337ab7;
}

.panelFooter
{
    float: left;
}
```

I realize some of the code isn't properly formatted, as I'm on mobile right now. Apologies for that.

Comment: What is with the space in "bootstrap.min.cs  s" `<link rel="stylesheet"               href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.cs  s"
 integrity="sha384-    1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"     crossorigin="anonymous" />`? Is it in the original source too?

Comment: In the original it'snot spaced. Must've just been a typing error on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following using z-index to have the drop down above the panel:

```
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* This was added to your code */
}
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. via W3C Schools

Comment: solved my issue. But is there any way to make the panel stay on the left side? On mobile, it stretches out.

Comment: Hi Donald, you could try the following:

1) Remove "float:left;" from the ".recent" class
2) Change "col-md-3" to "col-xs-12"
3) Then add a fixed or max-width to the ".panel" class such as 275px
4) Also review any @media queries that change the width of the bootstrap classes such as the ".container" class below 768px

Here is also a good resource for showing how the grid options work: 
- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

If this is not a fitting solution please add a working JS Fiddle or screen shots as well as further information as to what you wish to achieve.

Comment: I'll give that a try. What i'm trying to achieve is the same look that is on thedesktop style with the same code. I'm o mobile right now, so I can't provide a screen shot. If you want, you could view the code on your desktop/computer (if you're on one) to see what It looks like.

Comment: UPDATE: If trying the above I would also recommend wrapping the "col-xs-12" with another div that features the class "row" - this will help line things up better.

Comment: Why will that line things up better? I'm not really failiar with html, I'm just trying stuff. What better way to learn right? Anyways, is that a custom bootstrap class, or just regular html, with nothing done to it?